# jQuery - JSON basics: each( objJSON ) not working. Any solution?

Tags: jquery, json, while-loop, each

How can I make this work?

```
objJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(newjson.json);
var j = 0;
var n = objJSON.numberoflevels;

//NOW, THE IMPORTANT PART:
while (j < n) {
    $.each(objJSON.level[j], function (index, item){
        // instructions
    });
    j++;
}
```

I have a JSON document that is written like this:

```
{
    "numberoflevels": "3",
    "level0": [{
        "name": "1-ONE"
    }],
    "level1": [{
        "name": "1-TWO",
        "parent": "1-ONE"
    }],
    "level2": [{
        "name": "Croc Crocroc",
        "parent": "1-TWO"
    }, {
        "name": "Alan Algomas",
        "parent": "1-TWO"
    }]
}
```

What I want in that while is to parse inside the `each()` all the levels I have in the JSON

- j=1, level[ j ] = level1
- j=2, level[ j ] = level2
- etc

Comment: Can you amend the format of the JSON? It would make far more sense for the `levelX` objects to be in an array instead of having to concatenate the property name to retrieve them individually.

Comment: Yeah would be sweet... :) The problem is that my bosses are giving me this JSON to work and I can't change it. By the other hand the JSON could have any random number of levels, maybe 100, and I'm not nesting 100 levels at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use simple for in

```
for (key in objJSON) {
  if(key === 'numberoflevels') continue;
  console.log(key + ' command');
}
```

Comment: can you explain how does this work? I'm kinda noob working with JSONs

Comment: @Croc well JSON is object and 'for in' loop goes thru all keys in this object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp

Comment: Nice! Seems it's working. Let see if it can hold what I want it to do. Thanks man! +1

Comment: One more thing: While I'm going through the JSON this way, how can I do it to get the different informations of an array like "name" in "level2"?

Comment: with keys, something like `key[levelN].name`